# Making a shortcut for .getElementById

Tags: javascript

I want a shortcut for `someElement.getElementById`.

But instead of calling `.getElementById()`, how can I make it so I just say, like, `.foo()`?

For instance, I may say:

```
var element = document.foo("sampleID");
element.style.color = "red";
```

to change `color` style of the element with id `#sampleID` to red.

Or:

```
var element = document.foo("someDiv").foo("myElement");
element.style.backgroundColor = "blue"
```

To change the document's child with id `someDiv`'s child with ID `myElement`'s background color to blue.

In a clearer way, this would look for an element that is the child of the document and has ID `someDiv`. Then it would look for a child of that that has id `myElement`. Then it would change the background color of that to blue.

I tried to search the internet for these types of functions, but I have no idea what they're called, so I had no luck.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I added an example. Does that help?

Comment: You can assign any function to a variable or property: `document.foo = document.getElementById`.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. Don't define your own functions on built-in objects.

Comment: @Xufox So, would I just loop through every element?

Comment: @Quelklef Why loop?!

Comment: Because any property you add may be taken in the future, and you're building a (bad) API that only you understand.

Comment: @Xufox So that it would apply to every element `e` so I can do `e.foo()`

Comment: @Quelklef If you want to make a short-cut for `getElementById` on _any element_, then you could theoretically do `var foo='getElementById'; document[foo](`…`); element[foo](`…`)`.

Comment: IDs are unique. Therefore, there is no need to search for an element with one particular ID inside an element with another particular ID. More basically, `getElementById` is defined on the `document` only, not on arbitrary elements. Therefore, there is actually no way to search for an element with one ID within one with another idea with `getElementById`; you'd need to use `document.querySelector('#someDiv #myElement')`, but in all reasonable scenarios, that is exactly equivalent to `document.querySelector('#myElement')`, which is exactly equivalent to `document.getElementById('myElement')`.

Comment: @torazaburo The example was purely for explanation; I'd likely do all elements with tag name z or class name z under x parent element. I was not aware that `getElementById` is only valid on `document`, that nullifies my question entirely.

Comment: @torazaburo Please make an answer with your statement about `document` with `getElementById`, I will mark it as my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to alias `getElementById` to `foo`, then by all means, as other answers/comments suggest, do

```
document.foo = document.getElementById;
```

Probably not a very good idea, though.

But you appear to want to find elements with a particular ID inside elements with some other ID. But IDs are unique. Therefore, there is no need to search for an element with one particular ID inside an element with another particular ID. More basically, `getElementById` is defined on the `document` only, not on arbitrary elements.

Therefore, there is actually no way to search for an element with one ID within one with another idea with `getElementById`; you'd need to use `document.querySelector('#someDiv #myElement')`, but in all reasonable scenarios, that is exactly equivalent to `document.querySelector('#myElement')`, which is exactly equivalent to `document.getElementById('myElement')`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function foo(param) {
    doSomethingWith(param);
}
```

...and call it like this:

```
foo(param);
```

> But how can I make it so you instead call it like this?
>
> param.foo();

No, you don't. param is argument which can not call function.

By defining function of your requirement and returning its base object.

You can make same type of function for `ClassName` and others. It's better to use `jQuery` instead creating shortcut function. It has more utility and other basic and advance method to use.

```js
var byId = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

alert(byId('MY_ID').innerHTML);
```

```html
<p id="MY_ID">Hi</p>
```

Comment: right, except I want to say `alert(document.byId('MY_ID').innerHTML);`. That's what I'm asking for.

Comment: I don't really want to use JQ just because I don't do a ton in JS and don't want to load an entire library for something small.

Comment: @Quelklef Then make a global function `$` or `_` or whatever you want. There is no reason to attach your function to `document`.

Comment: @meagar But what If I don't want to search the child elements of `document` but instead of some specific element?

Comment: @Quelklef Then you should have been more clear in your question. No answers account for that requirement, because you didn't actually *say* that you wanted to do that. Again, the right answer is to use a global function and pass in a context argument.

Comment: @SarjanDesai I think I explained my question poorly. Please take another look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
document.foo = HTMLElement.prototype.foo = document.getElementById.bind(document);
```

will allow you to do `document.foo('id').foo('id2')`

--

`document` is an object and `getElementById` is a function that can be assigned to a property of such an object.

If you want to make `document.foo` work like `document.getElementById`, do

```
document.foo = document.getElementById
```

If you want to create a function on all `HTMLElement`s, then you should do

```
HTMLElement.prototype.foo = function() { ... }
```

You can't usually do `getElementById` on `HTMLElement`s since you should just call it on document instead (ids are supposed to be unique so it would have the same result).  If you really want to do this,

```
HTMLElement.prototype.foo = document.getElementById
```

--

More generally, for most values of `param`, you can set `param.foo =` anything you want, including functions

```
param.foo = function() { ... }
```

If you want this to apply to all elements of a particular type, you should attach it to the element's `prototype`.

For example, if you have a type `Bar`, then you would attach the function to `Bar.prototype` like

```
Bar.prototype.foo = function() { ... }
```

and instances of `Bar` will have a `foo()` function on them callable like

```
var b = new Bar(); b.foo();
```

Comment: But yes, as @meagar's comment says, this is generally a Really Bad Idea.